# Как сделать сетку (html, css)

Tags: html, css

не знаю как сделать сетку.
Она идёт сразу через несколько блоков и есть места(там где оранжевая стрелка и чуть выше), где не понятно каким образом можно сделать сетку(вертикальную часть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно предоставить HTML код, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавьте блокам css свойство `border`

Например

```
.row {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
.box {
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]